# Add a column of string using list's indices from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having this list of name:

```py
name_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
```

As well as the following `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'idx': ['(3,)','(3, 5)','(1, 3, 5)',
  '(1, 3, 5, 10)','(1, 3, 5, 8, 10)'],
 'score': [0.773,0.841,0.862,0.874,0.883]
    }
)

df.head(2)
    idx     score
0   (3,)    0.773
1   (3, 5)  0.841
```

The `idx` column represents indices of the elements of `name_list`. I want to add a new column `name` to the `df` with the corresponding name from the list.

**Expected results:**

```py
                idx     score             name
0              (3,)     0.773             (D,)
1             (3, 5)    0.841           (D, F)
2          (1, 3, 5)    0.862        (B, D, F)
3      (1, 3, 5, 10)    0.874     (B, D, F, K)
4   (1, 3, 5, 8, 10)    0.883  (B, D, F, I, K)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few steps:

- creating a mapping dictionary for the index -> value of the list,
- converting the strings representation of tuples to tuples with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval),
- mapping the values with a tuple comprehension

```
from ast import literal_eval

d = dict(enumerate(name_list))

df['name'] = [tuple(d.get(x, '?') for x in literal_eval(t))
              for t in df['idx']]
```

If you are sure that the indices are valid, no need for the dictionary:

```
df['name'] = [tuple(name_list[x] for x in literal_eval(t))
              for t in df['idx']]
```

For a string as output:

```
df['name'] = [f"({', '.join(tuple(name_list[x] for x in literal_eval(t)))})"
              for t in df['idx']]
```

Output:

```
                idx  score             name
0              (3,)  0.773             (D,)
1            (3, 5)  0.841           (D, F)
2         (1, 3, 5)  0.862        (B, D, F)
3     (1, 3, 5, 10)  0.874     (B, D, F, K)
4  (1, 3, 5, 8, 10)  0.883  (B, D, F, I, K)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `str.findall()` and `explode()`

```
df.assign(
    name = (df['idx'].str.findall(r'\d+')
            .explode()
            .astype(int)
            .map(dict(enumerate(name_list)))
            .groupby(level=0).agg(tuple)))
```

Output:

```
                idx  score             name
0              (3,)  0.773             (D,)
1            (3, 5)  0.841           (D, F)
2         (1, 3, 5)  0.862        (B, D, F)
3     (1, 3, 5, 10)  0.874     (B, D, F, K)
4  (1, 3, 5, 8, 10)  0.883  (B, D, F, I, K)
```